# jQuery enable prevent default and toggle an active class for first-child in a list

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Two small issues I cant seem to figure out:

1. As you come on to the page, I allow clicking of a thumbnail to go to a different page. However when I click on a button "Delete thumbs" I do NOT allow the user to click through, I use prevent default. Now my problem is when i then click the "done" button, the thumbs are still not clickable. I want to re-enable the clicking once you click "done"
2. My second issue is - If you click the button "delete thumbs" this will allow you to re-arrange the order of the thumbs using jQueryUI sortable.

I have an active class in the css set on the first-child. I want the active li only to be on the first one in the list. So If you drag the first li out it will remove the active class and  then the first li in the list will become the active one.

```
.gallery li a.active:first-child
```

I have the demo code below: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3E2Hg/73/

Hope someone can help,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, for your first question, here is the solution.

```
$(function cancelDeleteImages(){
    $(".cancelDeleteImages").click(function(event) {

        $('.cancelDeleteImages').hide(); 
        $('.deleteAllImages').show(); 

        $( "#sortable" ).sortable("disable");
        $('#sortable li a').unbind('click').click();
       // return true;
    });
});
```

Second question, i did not understand, can you please explain in detail

SECOND SOLUTION:

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            //Need to allow the user to be able to scrollover the thumbnails on device
            //delay: 900, // touch and hold to activate li being sortable
            //scroll: true, // allow user to scroll over thumbnails
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",

            stop: function(event, ui) {

           $('ul#sortable a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('ul#sortable a:first').addClass('active');
            }
        });
```

replace your .sortable with the above. works

Comment: cheers, 2nd question: on the fiddle if you click the delete "delete thumbs" button. you will see the first li is blue, if you drag that elsewhere in the list i want it to remove the active class of blue and always add the active class on the first li in the list?

Comment: dude, got the s0lution ;), have edited the code, just check. If this fixes your problem, please mark as correct

Comment: cheers mate, works a treat! I should really do another post but not sure if you have any ideas... When you click delete button and it allows you to reorder them. I am using a plugin called touch punch to make the sorting work on mobiles. However i was wondering if you might know how to allow scrolling over the thumbnails, at the moment you cant scroll over the thumbnails as it moves the list items. I was wondering if its possible to put a delay on selecting the li then allow scrolling over the thumbnails?

Answer (score 1):

FOR PROBLEM 1 - you can use the flag for that [**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3E2Hg/74/)

code -

```
var disonclick = false;

$(function deleteImage(){
    $(".deleteAllImages").click(function() {

        $('.deleteAllImages').hide();
        $('.cancelDeleteImages').show();

        //TODO: Need to disable href from being clickable when in delete mode
        disonclick = true;
        $('#sortable li a').click(function(e){
            if(disonclick) e.preventDefault();
        });        
        //TODO: Need to make active class toggle when first in the list (first li = active)

        $( "#sortable" ).sortable("enable");
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            //Need to allow the user to be able to scrollover the thumbnails on device
            //delay: 900, // touch and hold to activate li being sortable
            //scroll: true, // allow user to scroll over thumbnails
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
        });
    });
});

$(function cancelDeleteImages(){
    $(".cancelDeleteImages").click(function() {
        $('.cancelDeleteImages').hide(); 
        $('.deleteAllImages').show(); 
        disonclick = false;
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable("disable");  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [jQuery.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function for event handling, [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)/[unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) functions are serve as well

Prevent default click event by

```
$('#sortable li a').on("click",function() {
        return false;
    });
```

Enable with

```
$('#sortable li a').off("click");
```

[**demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/VZwV9/](http://jsfiddle.net/VZwV9/)

Hope this will help you on #1 issue